# Button Click to get Map

Tags: jquery, openlayers-3

This is the code in which when you click on map it calls the function. I want to call this function on a button click - is it possible to pass `evt` holding a map pixel?

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
   var place = null;
   allFeaturesAtPixel = [];
   map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
       allFeaturesAtPixel.push(feature);
       place = feature;
   });
   if (place) {
      var i; 
      for (i = 0; i < allFeaturesAtPixel.length; ++i) {
         console.log(allFeaturesAtPixel[i].get('name'));
      }
   }
   else{
       console.log("No feature");
   }
});
```

Comment: I'm reading your question as this: you want a function that you can call both from the map singleclick, and also separately from a button. When it is called from the button you want to pass in the evt with a pixel? If so I've posted a possible answer below. If not, can you explain a bit more what you need to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if you refactor the code into a separate function. You can then bind it to both the map singleclick, and also a button click. For the button click, you can supply a mock event with a property `pixel` of type `ol.Pixel` which in OpenLayers is just an array `[x, y]`. Here's how:

```
// Create the handler as a reusable function
function myHandler(evt) {
   var place = null;
   allFeaturesAtPixel = [];
   map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
       allFeaturesAtPixel.push(feature);
       place = feature;
   });
   if (place) {
      var i; 
      for (i = 0; i < allFeaturesAtPixel.length; ++i) {
         console.log(allFeaturesAtPixel[i].get('name'));
      }
   }
   else{
       console.log("No feature");
   }
}

// Now bind it to the map singleclick
map.on('singleclick', myHandler)

// Now bind it to your button, using a mock evt. I've used jQuery here.
$("#myButton").on('click', function() {
    var mock_evt = {pixel: [12, 13]}
    myHandler(mock_evt);
});
```